# How to prevent some x-blade attributes being rendered in html?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

everyone, currently I'm working on some Laravel project, where I want to have x-blade component which renders html depending on what attributes are passed to the component, but I don't want attributes themselves to be rendered in to the html.

**component blade file:**

```
@props([
    'variant'=>'red',
    'styles'=>[
        'red'=>'bg-red text-white h-11 px-4 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center font-bold',
        'white'=>'bg-white border border-red h-11 px-4 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center font-bold'
    ]
])

<a href="{{$attributes['href']}}" {{$attributes->merge(['class'=>$styles[$variant]])}}>
    {{$slot}}
    @if($attributes['external'])
        <div class="w-4 xl:w-5 4xl:w-6 ml-3 sm:ml-4">
            I'm external
        </div>
    @endif
</a>
```

**my component:**

```
<x-test href="#" class="w-max" variant="white" external>
    Button text
</x-test>
```

**rendered html:**

```
<a href="#" class="bg-white border border-red h-11 sm:h-12 xl:h-13 4xl:h-14 px-4 sm:px-7 xl:px-8 4xl:px-9 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center font-bold w-max" external="external">
    Button text
    <div class="w-4 xl:w-5 4xl:w-6 ml-3 sm:ml-4">
        I'm external
    </div>
</a>
```

as you can see `<a>` tag is being rendered with `external="external"` attribute and I want to prevent that.

Big thanks in advance for your time and energy!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

just declare `$external` in props to prevent that and use it like a normal variable

```
  @props([
      ...
      'external'=false
])

<a {{ $attributes }} {{$attributes->merge(['class'=>$styles[$variant]])}}>
    {{$slot}}
    @if($external)
        <div class="w-4 xl:w-5 4xl:w-6 ml-3 sm:ml-4">
            I'm external
        </div>
    @endif
</a>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, value is being set to false and conditional part is not rendered

Comment: <x-test  :external='true'>
    Button text
</x-test>

Comment: toogle true/false in blade when you want to use component

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```
 $attributes->merge(['class'=>$styles[$variant]])->except('external')
```

Comment: I have missed that when reading docs... Works perfectly!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @AurimasKuniutis if this answered your question you should mark it as such. It will help others as well if you do that.